# similar files has the same permission & owner but some of them give forbidden error

Tags: linux, centos5, file-permissions, permissions

I moved a file from another server to my server. in directory listing Apache doesn't show it and I cant download it from browser (forbidden) but I created a new file and chmod + chown both of them to the same thing and the one I created can be accessed but I still can't download the file moved from another server.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check SELinux properties.

`ls -Z` or `ls --scontext` will show you the properties.

You the need to change the security settings using `chcon` to their appropriate values.

Or you can just change the security properties on the file to the same ones as the file you created by using the following `chcon` command: 
 
`chcon --reference file_to_copy_from file_to_copy_to`

For more information on CentOS and SELinux, look [HERE](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux/).

Comment: Thanks, I disabled SELinux, and no change. I didn't understand how to fix this with `chcon` I have a file named test.tar that I can't acess it due forbidden error. ls -Z result: `-rw-r--r--  user user root:object_r:user_home_t        test.tar`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to nojak,

I fixed it with this command: `restorecon -v test.tar`

Comment: Glad to hear it!